# reCAPTCHA in Flask-User / Flask-WTForms: "site is verifying reCAPTCHA passed solutions less than 50% of the time"?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, recaptcha, flask-wtforms

I have integrated `reCAPTCHA` on a few of my pages via `Flask-User`, which uses in turn `Flask-WTF`. I have made a few tests and it seems to work great, but after one or two days I got the following message from google.com/recaptcha/admin:

[image]

And now I am not sure if I did something wrong or Google just haven't enough data to give me a correct feedback. Here is how I used the code:

In my main_app.py

```
app.config['RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY'] = '...my_keys...'
app.config['RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY'] = '...my_keys...'
```

In the Flask-User's `forms.py`

```
from flask_wtf import RecaptchaField
```

and then in each respective class I have used `recaptcha = RecaptchaField()`, so that I can use it via `Jinja2` within the html later.

```
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    recaptcha = RecaptchaField()
    ...

class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
    recaptcha = RecaptchaField()
    ...

class ForgotPasswordForm(FlaskForm):
    recaptcha = RecaptchaField()
    ...

class ResetPasswordForm(FlaskForm):
    recaptcha = RecaptchaField()
    ...
```

Here is an html example:

```
<form>
    ...
    ...
    {{ form.recaptcha }}

    {# Submit button #}
    ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize the registration form [(see doc)](https://flask-user.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing_forms.html#customizingformclasses) and add captcha field from `WTF`:

```
# Customize the Register form:
class CustomRegisterForm(RegisterForm):
  recaptcha= RecaptchaField()
```

then [(see WTF doc)](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/form.html#recaptcha) in the template `/flask-user/...` add `{{ form.recaptcha }}`